# how to subtract from this "not-best-practice-table"

Tags: php

Need help with the last part. how can I take the expense sum and subtract that from the income to get what leftover....

Income - Expense = leftover... you get the point..

Guess my mysql tables are not the best way to do it, but im a rookie and this is what I came up with...

```
// summary income

$query_income = "SELECT type, SUM(january), SUM(february), SUM(march), SUM(april),     SUM(may), SUM(june), SUM(juli), SUM(august), SUM(september), SUM(october), SUM(november), SUM(december) FROM data WHERE year = '2012' AND type = '1'";
$results = mysql_query($query_income);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $results )) {

   $total_income = $row['SUM(january)'] + $row['SUM(february)'] + $row['SUM(march)'] + $row['SUM(april)'] + $row['SUM(may)'] + $row['SUM(june)'] + $row['SUM(juli)'] + $row['SUM(august)'] + $row['SUM(september)'] + $row['SUM(october)'] + $row['SUM(november)'] + $row['SUM(december)'];

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><b>Income</b></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(january)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(february)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(march)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(april)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(may)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(june)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(juli)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(august)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(september)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(october)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(november)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row['SUM(december)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($total_income) ."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";

}

// summary expenses

$query_expense = "SELECT type, SUM(january), SUM(february), SUM(march), SUM(april), SUM(may), SUM(june), SUM(juli), SUM(august), SUM(september), SUM(october), SUM(november), SUM(december) FROM data WHERE year = '2012' AND type = '2'";
  $results = mysql_query($query_expense);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $results )) {

   $total_expense = $row1['SUM(january)'] + $row1['SUM(february)'] + $row1['SUM(march)'] + $row1['SUM(april)'] + $row1['SUM(may)'] + $row1['SUM(june)'] + $row1['SUM(juli)'] + $row1['SUM(august)'] + $row1['SUM(september)'] + $row1['SUM(october)'] + $row1['SUM(november)'] + $row1['SUM(december)'];


   echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><b>Expenses</b></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(january)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(february)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(march)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(april)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(may)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(june)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(juli)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(august)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(september)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(october)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(november)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($row1['SUM(december)']) ."</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'>" . number_format($total_expense) ."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";

}

// summary, whats left

   echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><b>Leftover</b></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:right'></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Store the income and expenses in their own variables. Print their differences.

Comment: that would be the thing I need help with...

Comment: For example: $decemberIncome = number_format($row['SUM(december)']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT 
    income.1 - expense.1 AS 1,
    income.2 - expense.2 AS 2,
    income.3 - expense.3 AS 3,
    income.4 - expense.4 AS 4,
    income.5 - expense.5 AS 5,
    income.6 - expense.6 AS 6,
    income.7 - expense.7 AS 7,
    income.8 - expense.8 AS 8,
    income.9 - expense.9 AS 9,
    income.10 - expense.10 AS 10,
    income.11 - expense.11 AS 11,
    income.12 - expense.12 AS 12
FROM
    (SELECT
        SUM(january) AS 1, 
        SUM(february) AS 2,  
        SUM(march) AS 3,  
        SUM(april) AS 4,  
        SUM(may) AS 5,  
        SUM(june) AS 6,  
        SUM(juli) AS 7,  
        SUM(august) AS 8,  
        SUM(september) AS 9, 
        SUM(october) AS 10, 
        SUM(november) AS 11, 
        SUM(december) AS 12
    FROM data 
    WHERE year = '2012' AND type = '1') income,
    (SELECT type  AS 1,  
        SUM(january) AS 1, 
        SUM(february) AS 2,  
        SUM(march) AS 3,  
        SUM(april) AS 4,  
        SUM(may) AS 5,  
        SUM(june) AS 6,  
        SUM(juli) AS 7,  
        SUM(august) AS 8,  
        SUM(september) AS 9, 
        SUM(october) AS 10, 
        SUM(november) AS 11, 
        SUM(december) AS 12
    FROM data 
    WHERE year = '2012' AND type = '2') expense
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query like this:

```
SELECT type, SUM(january) AS `jan`, SUM(february) AS `feb`, ...
FROM data
WHERE `year` = '2012'
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type ASC
```

Then the handle the results like:

```
$totals = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $results )) {
   $type = 'unknown';
   switch ((integer)$row['type']) {
       1:
           $type = 'income';
           break;
       2:
           $type = 'expense';
           break;
   }
   unset($row['type']);
   $totals[$type] = $row;
}

$total_income = array_sum($totals['income']);
$total_expense = array_sum($totals['expenses']);
```

Now you have a multidimensional array that you can easily work with to sum the entire arr

Comment: I prefer to do it on the database side, but I like this approach.